# Pushing changes made in a local branch to a remote remote if the branch doesn’t exist in remote yet

Tags: github, branch, git-branch, git-push

My project leader has a remote git repo named repo-A. He created a new branch named branch-a and he has been working on a feature on this branch. He gave me a small task to do and I cloned this branch-a to my local repo. I created a new branch from branch-a named branch-b and made my changes in this. Now, How do I push it back as branch-b does not exist in the remote yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push with set upstream option activated:

```
git push --set-upstream origin branch_b
```